# Connecting Eclipse, Websphere and DB2

Tags: eclipse, db2, websphere

I would like to know which versions of Java, Eclipse and Websphere are compatible with each other. I have tried installing Websphere and DB2 over and over again and have faced issues with the java version once and with the webspere configs a few times. Can you tell me what versions i need to use and how i should go about setting up the entire set of services on my system? This requirement is ASAP.

Comment: Please indicate the error messages, error codes, etc. in order to understand clearly the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse normally comes with a JRE, so there is not need to configure Java.

I think WebSphere comes also with its own Java (J9 I think).

DB2 does not need Java to run, but it also comes with a JRE to execute Java Stored Procedures.

In order to connect Eclipse with DB2, you will use JDBC, and it does not care about versions. As previously said, you could use Data Studio that comes with the necessary elements to connect to a bunch of databases.

WebSphere also uses JDBC to connect to DB2, so there is not a problem here neither. Eventually, you have to include the necessary jars to connect to the database. You can get them by downloading the [IBM DataServer client](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=4020&uid=swg27016878).

Finally, if you want to control WebSphere from Eclipse, that is another thing and the problem is only about configuration.

Answer (score 0):

For the runtime requirements (e.g. OS and Database), start [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=180&uid=swg27006921).

For Eclipse, I think only WAS 6.0 and WebSphere Community Edition are supported by the Web Tools Project. You'll need one of the Rational branded Eclipse versions (Rational Application Developer) to have local test environments for WAS 6.1, 7.0, or 8.0.

Answer (score 0):

If you like to use Eclipse as your Java development environment I recommend that you get IBM Data Studio v3.1. It is an Eclipse IDE, it is free and it has a lot of tools for database development and administration built in. It will work with all currently supported versions of DB2 for LUW, DB2 for z/OS, DB2 for i5/OS and even Oracle. Ir also supports all current versions of WebSphere Application Server (I think v6 and higher). You don't have to worry about Java levels as it comes with supported JDK. You can download it from [the DB2 Express-C site](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/db2/express/download.html?S_TACT=LKFREE000&S_CMP=ECDDWW01). For your needs you will probably want "Data Studio IDE". While there you may also want to get DB2 Express-C a free version of DB2 that has all of the functionality of the other higher value editions of DB2.